# a product is used after beeing disposed?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, setstate, provider

I am building a shop app and made a toggle method between all and favorites but when i set some products as favourite and open the favourite screen and go back to all screen i find that the other products is gone and give me an error on the `dart final product = Provider.of<Product>(context);`   the error says  **Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (A Product was used after being disposed.
Once you have called dispose() on a Product, it can no longer be used.) **[enter image description here][1]

````dart
class Products with ChangeNotifier {
      List<Product> _items = [
        Product(
          id: 'p1',
          title: 'Red Shirt',
          description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
          price: 29.99,
          imageUrl:
              'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
        ),
        Product(
          id: 'p2',
          title: 'Trousers',
          description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
          price: 59.99,
          imageUrl:
              'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg',
        ),
        Product(
          id: 'p3',
          title: 'Yellow Scarf',
          description: 'Warm and cozy - exactly what you need for the winter.',
          price: 19.99,
          imageUrl:
              'https://live.staticflickr.com/4043/4438260868_cc79b3369d_z.jpg',
        ),
        Product(
          id: 'p4',
          title: 'A Pan',
          description: 'Prepare any meal you want.',
          price: 49.99,
          imageUrl:
              'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg/1024px-Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg',
        ),
      ];
    
      var _showFavourite = false;
    
      List<Product> get items {
        // if(_showFavourite) {
        //   return _items.where((prd) => prd.isFavourite).toList();
        // }
        return [..._items];
      }
    
      List<Product> get favourite {
        return _items.where((prod) => prod.isFavourite).toList();
      }
    
      Product findByid(String id) {
        return _items.firstWhere((prd) => prd.id == id);
      }
    
      

  

  void addProduct() {
    //items.add()
    notifyListeners();
  }
}```
 this is product code


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPaez.jpg
````

Comment: Can you paste the code of Product?

Comment: @ACR i add it ```dart

Comment: Is the code to make the item as favourite in this Product class? May be when you are setting an item as favourite, there is some error....can you move  that code for making an item as favourite here?

Comment: @ACR ```dart void toggleFavourite() {
    isFavourite = !isFavourite;
    notifyListeners();
  }
} ```

Comment: Hi, can you write the toggle as :     void toggleFavourite(bool stat, Product prod) {
    _items.firstWhere((prd) => prd.id == prod.id).isFavourite = stat;
    notifyListeners();
  }

Comment: Pass the status(to favourite or not) and the Product which has to be updated to the above method.